# Angular Select Default Options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I have a select tag that may or may not have options loaded. Everything is fine when the options are provided, but whenever I want a default option to display only when no other options exist, the default option will not appear. The end result is that I have no options available. If you remove the two items in the `countries` variable, then you will see what I mean. What's wrong and how do I fix this?

MY [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9w5XT/5/)

## JS code

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);

function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.countries = [
        {name: 'United States'},
        {name: 'Canada'}    
    ]     
}
```

## HTML

```
<div ng-app="App" >
 <div ng-controller="ctrl">
<select multiple="" ng-multiple="true"  ng-model="country_selected"
     data-ng-options="country.name for country in countries">
    <option value="" ng-hide="countries.length == 0">No countries found</option>
</select>

  </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: trying to hide `<option>` doesn't work in most versions of IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Use two selects to switch

   see an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6BhPu3yjWW7FB3teDGpW?p=preview)
2. Write a custom directive